# Not able to compile .ts to .js in Vs - windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am new to typescript and all i want to do is convert my typescript file to javascript
when i do npm typescript --verison, i get as 3.10.10

i have my **task.json** file like this

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "${cwd}/node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "-p",
        "."
    ],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

and **tsconfig.json** file like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

when i do tsc mock.ts tsc, i get an error like this

> 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

after a little research from the blog i used this in my tasks.json file

> "command": "${cwd}/node_modules/.bin/tsc.cmd",
>   but i am not able to compile my .ts file into javascript

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes that will hopefully help

- `npm typescript --verison` is returning the version of npm, not TypeScript (3.1 is very outdated so you might want to update that first `npm i -g npm`)
- The way to run tsc will vary depending on whether you installed it globally (`npm install typescript`) or locally (`npm install --save-dev typescript`).

If you add a script to your package.json file, it should handle locating the typescript package for you regardless of whether it was installed globally or locally.  Ex:

in package.json

`...
"scripts": {
  "tsc": "tsc"
}
...`

Then run the TypeScript compiler like so: `npm run tsc -- <your typescript options>`.  Ex: `npm run tsc -- --version` should then return the actual version of typescript (or tell you that TypeScript is not really installed).

You can also checkout `npm ls` if you want to do some more digging into whether TypeScript is installed.